# Entity Framework, have I added this entry before?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a simple Entity.

```
public partial class Thing
{
    public Thing()
    {}

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

I am inserting thousands of new entries into a localDB database, but there will only be a few hundered unique things. 
If I SaveChanges after every insert, then it will run very slow, but if I don't SaveChanges then I can't tell whether the newThing.Name already exists. 
Or can I? I am quite foggy on checking where something exists in the context vs the database vs pre/post SaveChanges. Can anyone clarify this for me?

```
Thing newThing = new Thing();
newThing.Name = "MyName";

context.Things.Add(d);

//returns null
Thing myFirstThing = context.Things.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == newThing.Name);

//returns false 
if (context.Detectors.Any(c => c.Name == newThing.Name))
{  //do some stuff}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can probably do this with the ChangeTracker on your DbContext, BUT, it would probably be slow.

```
//(warning: free-handing this):
myContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<theEntityType>().Any(e => e.State == EntityState.Added && e.Entity.TheField == yourString);
```

I think that (or something close would work, but it could get very slow, as you are scanning a collection with each call. (it would get a little slower after each add -- a collection with 1000's of members would burn a lot of ticks)

Instead, you could add the entity to a Dictionary<yourString, theEntity> as you add them.  Key-based lookups in a dictionary are O(1), so even if you have a million entries in the dictionary, the lookup is very fast.  Clear the dictionary when you save the entity to stay lighter on memory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I will go with your Dictionary idea. There are only 400ish unique entries.  I'll probably use a List<string> though.

Comment: @kurgaan Glad to help.  If you use a List though, you won't get the performance of a dictionary.  When you search a list, it just loops through the list.  If you use a Dictionary or Hashset, it does not do a simple loop -- it's more like having an index, and you will get much better performance on the lookup.